# Refresh custom lightning component from standard related list in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

In my Opportunity flexi page, i have related list of a custom Object X and also a custom component for the same object (X) on the right hand panel, all in a same flexi page. When i make changes/add a record using the related list my custom component in the right panel is not reflecting the changes. I need to refresh the browser to reflect the changes. How to overcome this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way we found to be working is to listen to standard [`force:showToast`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation) application event / toast message:

```
<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.onShowToast}" />
```

Seems bit hacky; but works due to the fact that editing or deleting a record from standard related list always shows a toast message.

Downside is that component would refresh with toast message from any component, still something is better than nothing.

Comment: Raul, i tried this approach but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Maverick I see, been a while I worked on Aura component as we moved to LWC, originally I meant it to be is `force:showToast`, updated the answer

Comment: Raul, by adding force:showToast it worked.. Thanks